# Jquery DataTable plugin not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am working on a project in VS 2015 community edition, i was trying to use the jquery datatable plugin and followed all steps showed in tutorial but still i am unable to use the plugin. I have already installed the jquery.datatables package through package manager which installed successfully, then added the scripts in bundle.config too, but my page is loading without Datatable plugin, i also installed bootbox plugin which is working fine. Need help , i am sharing the code and the snaps!

P.S: My VS intelligence is not giving suggestion for Datatable and when i restarted VS and tried to bhild the project i got the following error.(When running VS as admin, i don't get this error but Datatable plugin still not works.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euqgf.png)

[Installed Successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhWxf.png)

[VS intelligence not giving suggestion for DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eToMZ.png)

[Page loaded after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43sbI.png)

BundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Vidly
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootbox.js",
                        "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                        "~/scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.js",
                        "~/scripts/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));



            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/content/datatables/css/datatables.bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Index.html

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Customer>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>

@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p>We don't have any customers yet</p>
}
else
{
    <table id="customers" class=  "table table-bordered table-hover" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Customers
                </th>
                <th>Membership Type</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var customer in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Edit", "Customers", new { id = customer.Id}, null )
                    </td>
                    <td>@customer.MembershipType.Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-customer-id="@customer.Id" class="btn-link js-delete">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
}

@section scripts
    {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("customers").DataTable();

            $("#customers").on("click", ".js-delete", function () {
                var button = $(this);

                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this customer?", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/customers/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                            method: "DELETE",
                            success: function () {
                                button.parents("tr").remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });                
            });
        });
    </script>    
    }
```

Comment: `$("customers").DataTable();` should be `$("#customers").DataTable();`

Comment: Oh my god! That single # wasted my hours! Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, always the way ;-)